# C# get concrete version of floating version package used in build

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, version

I want to always use the latest version of a specific package, but need to mark my output with the version of that package.

I set up floating versions to always get the latest:

```
<PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="1.0.*"/>
```

This makes it impossible to parse the .csproj file beforehand. Is there some tool I can use or an output file which contains this information? Or is there another way to get the latest version? The solution has to work in CI.

Answer (score 0):

This information is in `obj/project.assets.json` which is generated during the restore